# Convert 1 to 12 (number type) to January to December using just Power Query and not with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

How do I replicate the below DAX Calculated column solution to a Power Query Custom Column solution instead?

```
Short Month =
SWITCH (
    Some_Table_Name[Month],
    1, "Jan",
    2, "Feb",
    3, "Mar",
    4, "Apr",
    5, "May",
    6, "Jun",
    7, "Jul",
    8, "Aug",
    9, "Sep",
    10, "Oct",
    11, "Nov",
    12, "Dec",
    BLANK ()
)
```

I know I can just use the DAX solution but if it can be done via Power Query then I would appreciate if I would learn or know it too.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as part of a date and convert to text:

```
Date.ToText(#date(2000,[Month],1),"MMM")
```

Comment: But my column is of number type, screenshot above. I would like to have a one-step transformation.

Comment: This expects a number type for [Month].

Comment: Wow, thank you. I will try this out. May I know what the "1" argument is for?

Comment: It's the day of the month since the format is `#date(year,month,day)`. You can use anything less than 28 for the day or another year in the first argument since it's really just the month that matters.